# Почему url профиля работает только для одного пользователя? django

Tags: python, django, url

Я делаю регистрацию на django и мне осталось совсем чуть-чуть.
После profile/ идет имя пользователя, за которого я вошел и все работает.

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/Vanilin_Ivanov

НО! у меня есть еще другие зарегистрированные пользователи и если вставить их имя в url, выведется условие 404 во views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


class Profile(TemplateView):
template_name = 'registration/profile.html'

def get(self, request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html')
```

Примечание: это условие прописано потому, что вместо имени пользователя можно было писать любые символы, но при этом страница профиля все равно отображалась. и когда я вставлял имя другого зарегистрированного, у меня все так же оставался профиль пользователя за которого Я ВОШЕЛ

Сейчас, видимо, ничего сильно не изменилось, только теперь идет 404.

url профиля, представленный в приложении registration urls.py:

```
#urls.py
from .views import Profile
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
path('profile/<str:username>', Profile.as_view(), name='profile'),
...другие url...
```

]

и вот ссылка на профиль в шаблоне:

```
#registration/profile.html
<a href="{% url 'profile' request.user.username %}">
    {% avatar user 100 class="Avatar" %}
</a>
```

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так, чтобы работали ссылки на других зарегистрированных пользователей, а не только того, за которого я вошел.

Примечание: для регистрации я использую django-allaouth

Answer (score 0):

В `request.user` хранится пользователь, который авторизован в данный момент.
Если вы хотите, что бы по ссылке открывался профиль пользователя, то вам нужно передать в `html` всех пользователей.

**views.py**

```
def all_users(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all_users.html', {'users': users})


class Profile(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/profile.html'

    def get(self, request, username):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'user': user})
```

**html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile' user.username %}">
        {% avatar user 100 class="Avatar" %}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: аватар перестал показываться, а если взять в цикл весь шаблон, то вся страница пустая, что не так?

Comment: @tammalako Покажите модель пользователя. Я так понимаю, вы её расширяли?